# How do I retrieve the indexes of a double for loop given the iteration count?

Tags: c, loops

Let us say I have a double for loop.

```
/*Just a double for loop
*/    
for(int i = 0; i<IMAX; i++){
 for(int j = 0; j<JMAX; j++){
   count++;
   recover_loop_indices(count,IMAX,JMAX); /*this is not real world code.Just to illustrate what I mean*/
 }
}
```

My question is precisely, given `count`, `IMAX` and `JMAX`, is it possible to recover the unique loop indices, i and j?

Comment: i think this would be better suited for stackoverflow?

Comment: @iamjackbauer: not the downvoter (here, have a +1), but my guess is because it's probably a SO question, since there's a clear answer with little/no discussion.

Comment: @insta: thanks. Oh yes. This belongs on SO actually. I almost did n t notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, based on count:

```
i = floor(count / JMAX);
j = count % JMAX;
```

You don't need IMAX at all. In fact, this is often how one can reconstruct an image from a serial stream of pixels, given only the width of the stream.

Edit:

I am assuming you want to recover the values of i and j *before* the count++. To recover it after the count++, use (count-1).

Comment: Just expanding on Kevin Hsu's answer, by reconstructing an image, he means constructing an image(in 2D form) from the pixel stream(1D) and width of the image. A 256x256 image is a 1D pixel stream of size (256*256)

Comment: yes. that works. I am now wondering how this would change for indexes from arbitrary starting points(instead of from 0) and increment by a step (instead of by 1). example for (int i = ISTART; i < IMAX; i+=ISTEP)..I ll post the solution once i m done.